# Enviar varios parámetros a través de la Url

Tags: javascript, html, c#, webforms

Buen día tengo el siguiente código:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "imprimir", $"ImprimirReporte('Reportes/ImprimirTiquete.aspx?IdTiquete={IdTiquete}','ImprimirTiquete');", true);
```

Donde puedo enviar un parámetro y abrir otra pagina donde se me despliega las impresoras que el usuario puede escoger, pero requiero enviar un segundo parámetro y no se como hacerlo, intente de esta forma y me genera un error

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "imprimir", $"ImprimirReporte('Reportes/ImprimirTiquete.aspx?IdTiquete={IdTiquete}?Impresionveces=1','ImprimirTiquete');", true);
```

Si alguien me puede orientar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas que mandar los demás parámetros utilizando `&` El primer parámetro se define con `?` y los subsecuentes con `&`

Por ejemplo:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "imprimir", $"ImprimirReporte('Reportes/ImprimirTiquete.aspx?IdTiquete={IdTiquete}&Impresionveces=1','ImprimirTiquete');", true);
```